# Excel aligning data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in excel that repeats the numbers 1 to 5 (A), in the next column is a list of numbers that I want to match (B), with the condition of one matching number per 1 to 5 in A. An example is below first 2 columns are what I have now, second 2 columns are what I am hoping to find a formula for. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
A   B       A   B
1   2       1   
2   3       2   2
3   2       3   
4           4   
5           5   
1           1   
2           2   
3           3   3
4           4   
5           5   
1           1   
2           2   2
3           3   
4           4   
5           5   
1   3       1   
2   3       2   
3   2       3   3
4           4   
5           5   
1           1   
2           2   
3           3   3
4           4   
5           5   
1           1   
2           2   2
3           3   
4           4   
5           5
```

Comment: What is the role for generating the output? How your current & desired situations are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the items from the source table in column B:

```
=FILTER(B3:B32,B3:B32<>"")
```

Then, assign a "group" to each group of 1-5 in column A:

```
=ROUNDUP((ROW()-2)/5,0)
```

Then retrieve from the filtered items, the item corresponding to the group number:

```
=INDEX(G3#,J3:J32,1)
```

Next, check if the retrieved item number matches the column A number on the same row:

```
=I3#=K3#
```

Finally, if they match, return the value from column A:

```
=IF(L3#,K3#,"")
```

As a single formula, this can be achieved with the following formula, which assumes your match items are in column B and the list of 1-5 is in column I:

```
=IF(INDEX(FILTER($B$3:$B$32,$B$3:$B$32<>""),ROUNDUP((ROW()-2)/5,0),1)=$I3,$I3,"")
```

The image below shows the process.

[image]